# UFW blocking webrick on port 3000

Tags: firewall, ruby, ufw

On a ubuntu 10.0.4 server runs redmine. starting webrick with:

```
./server webrick -e production -b lvps46-173-79-113.dedicated.hosteurope.de -d
```

makes redmine available in browser. as soon as we enable ufw, webrick can´t be accessed anymore.
of course we allowed Port 3000 from anywhere

```
ufw allow 3000/tcp
ufw allow 3000/udp
```

find the whole iptables output here http://pastebin.com/k6WNqdPU

checking

```
lsof -ni tcp:2222
```

tells me ruby is listening on port 3000

```
ruby    3457 root    5u  IPv4 864846667      0t0  TCP 46.173.79.113:3000 (LISTEN)
```

What else can we check? what´s wrong with the ufw rules for port 3000?

Comment: The iptables test you show is pretty much meaningless, not least because it completely overlooks the possible effects of a blanket DROP policy.  If you could cut and paste the entire output of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question, we may be able to shed some light.

Comment: Hi Mad thanks for this good idea, unfortunately it´s quite long is there are part which is of most interest?

Comment: Because iptables rules work on first-match-wins, no part is meaningful in isolation.  As long as you paste it in and use SF's built-in formatting engine to declare it as a code sample, the site will box it with its own scrollbar, so you don't need to worry too much about the length.

Comment: edited the question with iptables output ;)

Comment: It looks fine, and should be allowing inbound TCP to port 3000 and outbound responses.  Can you confirm that there's no *other* firewall in front of this machine?

Comment: Thanks mad, yes I can confirm and if I disable ufw. redmine is available, means it must be something wrong with the rules

Comment: There's something odd going on here.  When I run those iptables rules you posted through the grep you posted, I **do** get some output.  That is, the data you've posted seem to me to be self-inconsistent, which makes the problem fairly hard to diagnose.  Any comment?

Comment: Hi Mad, well what to reply to your comment. sounds like an endpoint … still hoping one had run into something similar. as said … turning ufw of brings webrick online, it must have something to do with ufw rules

Comment: I repeat my question: do you have any idea why the `iptables` ruleset you show contains lines that contain the word "3000", but you say that when you do `iptables -Ln|grep 3000` you get no output?

Comment: double checked sorry, when I did the first grep ufw was disabled thus the 3000 was not there and could not be greped. I´ve edited my question thus the iptables of pastebin reflects the actual situation.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, ufw will block input that isn't specifically allowed.  It sounds like you "allow 3000/tcp" isn't taking affect.  Take a look at ufw's status with

```
ufw status verbose
```

Make sure it says "Status: Active" and note the default policy (typically "Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)").

Comment: checked, also the order of the rules. any clue why else a rule can be ignored?

Comment: If ufw is "Active" but you don't see any rule in iptables then I would try reloading ufw.  Also, check the ufw log in /var/log/ufw.log to see if that helps any.